# Charts.js -> Display / Load chart only when visible on the screen

Tags: chart.js

This is my first question, I was searching for the answer here and on Google but to no avail.

I am preparing a website for accountancy company, they have requested a demo to be created with some data visualisations. I have opted to use 'charts.js'.

My problem is this, I want the chart to load only when visible on the screen. At the moment they all load at the same time therefore you miss the quite nice animation.

Extending on my question, I would like text next to the chart to 'ease-in' too, also only when visible on screen.

Would someone be kind enough to point me to the right material on the 'net, or maybe show me an easy way to achieve this?

Kindest regards and thank you in advance!

As requested, I am adding simple code that displays two charts below the screen. To make this work you will need Chart.js from here: [Chart.js Website](http://www.chartjs.org/)

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Graphs</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <script src="js/Chart.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

<div class="graphs">        

            <div class="separator1"></div>


            <div class="graph1">

                    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="475" height="400">Graph 1</canvas>
                    <script>
                    //Get the context of the canvas element we want to select
                    context = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');
var Line = {};
var data = {
    labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
    datasets : [
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(151,57,56,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(151,57,56,1)",
            pointColor : "rgba(151,57,56,1)",
            pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
            data : [65,59,90,81,56,55,40]
        },
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(59,97,150,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(59,97,150,1)",
            pointColor : "rgba(59,97,150,1)",
            pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
            data : [28,48,40,19,96,27,100]
        }
    ]
};
var options = { scaleOverlay : false, scaleOverride : false, scaleLineWidth : 1,  pointDotRadius : 3, pointDotStrokeWidth : 1, animationSteps : 150 };

new Chart(context).Line(data, options);

                    </script>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text1">
                        <div class="innertext">
                        <h3>Praesent viverra</h3>
                        <hr/>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>




        <div class="graph2">

                    <canvas id="myCanvas2" width="475" height="400">Graph 2</canvas>
                    <script>
                    //Get the context of the canvas element we want to select
                    context = document.getElementById('myCanvas2').getContext('2d');
var Pie = {};
var data = [
    {
        value: 30,
        color:"#973938"
    },
    {
        value : 50,
        color : "#78963E"
    },
    {
        value : 40,
        color : "#3B6196"
    },
    {
        value : 25,
        color: "#F49D20"
    },
    {
        value : 35,
        color: "#FBDD13"
    }           
];
var options = { animationSteps : 150 };

new Chart(context).Pie(data, options);

                    </script>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text2">
                        <div class="innertext">
                        <h3>Praesent viverra</h3>
                        <hr/>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

main.css:

```
.graph1 {
    margin-left: 15%;
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
    height: 450px;
    display: block;
}

.graph1 canvas {
    padding: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
}

.graph2 {
    margin-right: 15%;
    width: 33%;
    float: right;
    height: 450px;
    display: block;
}

.graph2 canvas {
    padding: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
}


.innertext {
    padding-top: 25%;

}

.text1 {
    margin-right: 15%;
    width: 33%;
    float: right;
    height: 450px;

}

.text1 p {
    text-align: center;
}

.text1 hr {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 40%;
    text-align: center;
}

.text1 h3 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #636363;
}


.text2 {
    margin-left: 15%;
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
    height: 450px;

}

.text2 p {
    text-align: center;
}

.text2 hr {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 40%;
    text-align: center;
}

.text2 h3 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #636363;
}

.separator1 {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
}
```

Thanks again to anyone willing to help!

Comment: Show us some code so we might help you

Comment: I can add code that displays the graphs and text but that is just basic HTML and CSS. I havent actually made any progress further than that I am afraid. I guess I can post simple HTML and CSS as a starting point for people like yourself who are willing to help.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out